# Stumped by a pretty basic fraction division

Tags: arithmetic, self-learning, fractions

I'm self-studying through Stroud & Booths's amazing "Engineering Mathematics", 7th Edition, and am still on the "Arithmetic" section. Even though I've gone through the whole chapter and a lot of the practice exercises, I'm still stumped by some occasionally. Here's one:

I'm supposed to present this fraction as a number raised to a power:

$$6^2 \div 5^{-2}$$

My trusty calculator says that the final result is 75, but that's not the point of the exercise. Any guidance, please? :)

Comment: The division you posted is certainly not equal to $75$.

Comment: Your trusty calculator is wrong.  Your expression is $6^2\times 5^2=36\times 25=900$.

Comment: $5^{-2}=\frac{1}{5^2}$.

Comment: Your calculator is not so trusty, or you didn't use it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all doesn't the calculation evaluate to 900? 
But if you want to put the final answer as a number to an exponent, here's what you do.

$6^2 / 5^{-2}
= 6^2 / (1/5^2)
= 6^2 * 5^2
= (6*5)^2
= 30^2$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Any number of the form $a^{-b}$ is the same as $1/a^b$.

For example, $a/c^{-b} = a/(1/c^b) = a*c^b$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{6^2}{5^{-2}} = 6^2\cdot 5^2 = 30^2=900.
$$